# Adding Outlines to Plot with Multiple Histograms Side by Side

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am using matplotlib to create a plot with multiple histograms. The template code that I am using for my graphs is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/multiple_histograms_side_by_side.html). I am trying to outline the histograms, so I modified the code in the for-loop to include the edgecolor argument like this:

```
for x_loc, binned_data in zip(x_locations, binned_data_sets):
    lefts = x_loc - 0.5 * binned_data
    ax.barh(centers, binned_data, height=heights, left=lefts, edgecolor='k')
```

but for my end result I get a plot with vertical lines:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC4lF.png)
Is there any way to get rid of the vertical lines and just keep the outlines? (As a side note, my graph looks different from the example because I used different data, but the code is pretty much the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical lines are appearing because there are edgelines being drawn for bins that have no data (value of `binned_data` item == 0 )

You could use a boolean mask such that the `ax.barh()` only plots for those that have data.

Using the same for-loop segment you sent:

```
for x_loc, binned_data in zip(x_locations, binned_data_sets):
    # boolean mask for just plotting those with values > 0
    draw_line_mask = binned_data>1
    
    lefts = x_loc - 0.5 * binned_data
    
    # filter data using mask
    ax.barh(
        centers[draw_line_mask],
        binned_data[draw_line_mask],
        height=heights[draw_line_mask],
        left=lefts[draw_line_mask],
        edgecolor='k')
```

Output graph:

[image: Output Graph]